# Загрузка - Автозапуск программы ДО ВХОДА пользователей в систему

Tags: windows-10, реестр, автозапуск

Как сделать так, чтоб программа запускалась, до входа (сразу после загрузки Windows) пользователя в систему (ввода им пароля).
Ключи реестра:

```
«HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run»
```

и темболее

```
«HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run»
```

- не помогают.
В других местах, пишут, что «До входа пользователя в систему могут запускаться только сервисы»
Так что переделывать программу под сервис?

Можно конечно попробовать через gpedit.msc ("*Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Startup/Shutdown*")), но программа не запускается. Точнее запускается, но эта программа в свою очередь запускает "bat", который в свою очередь запускает программу с параметрами, которая работает с видеокартами, которая начинает выкидывать ошибки.

Comment: *"Так что переделывать программу под сервис?"* А это проблема?

Comment: просто никогда еще не переделывал, думал можно проще поступить